SwiftUI TabView got wrong width in NavigationSplitView's side bar view when running on iPad simulator
I've been learning SwiftUI for a while, and it's really great. I run into a layout problem when I tried to add a TabView in sidebar view of NavigationSplitView. It's running as expected on iPhone simulator and Mac, but the width of TabView is wrong when running on iPad. It's wider than the sidebar that containing it.
Am I doing something wrong? Please help. Thanks.
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            TabView {
                Text("This is sidebar 1")
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Sidebar 1")
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                Text("This is sidebar 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Sidebar 2")
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(1)
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("This is detail")
        }
    }
}



Used a custom view with same result.


There are many SO posts that says
TabView should not be inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView or
the deprecated NavigationView. It should be the top most container. Although I haven't seen any Apple documentation on this.

@workingdogsupportUkraine This is true for UIKit. However, I don't see a reason, why this UI component should not be embeddable in any other view in SwiftUI, unless for Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. The issue though, seems to be an layout issue. Call it a bug. One can workaround this by adding a padding(2) with a small value to the TabView. I still would be careful though, because TabView may sill be dependent on legacy UIKit constraints causing undesired side effects.

The default TabView should not be embedded in a NavigationSplitView or NavigstionStack. Apple’s HIG clearly states that tabs should be mutually exclusive. They cannot have shared navigation it will lead to endless bugs. In iOS 18 which should be released out of beta after the 9th NavigationSplitView has a TabView style. You have to create a custom TabView for this to work.

@loremipsum It’s nice to hear that Apple is rolling out this feature, but unfortunately, I couldn’t get it to work with a custom TabView either, check out my 2nd pic, same result. Thanks anyway.

@CouchDeveloper Thanks. A little padding fixed the width problem. I didn’t intend to use it in any existing projects; I was just messing around :D
